# Turn on Autocommit for simple Pojo data objects?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my application I have hidden the underlying storage objects behind interfaces, allowing me to switch storage at will.

The issue is that when testing hibernate it seems that Hibernate is very Transaction oriented. Everything that I could find on the subject (mainly [their official docs](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode)) says that autocommit is bad and should rarely be used. However my entire application isn't written around Hibernate, its written around the interfaces. This means that getting data from the database happens in one method (eg getObjects() in the factory), not a Transaction.

Since I've abstracted away the storage implementation, is autocommit the right solution? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: Turning on auto-commit does not mean that you no longer use transactions. Each statement will run in it's own transaction.

Comment: @Vineet Maybe I could of rephrased that better. I was meaning that other parts of the code should use transactions to get data (beginTransaction(), get or set data, commit()), not the pojo itself.

Comment: Well, what does the POJO do if other parts are performing data access, and by inference, why should the POJO now worry about auto-commits?

Comment: @Vineet Well they can wait or something. It does present a challenge, but its what I need to do as project has no knowledge of the underlying storage. I'm persisting my data, not my entire project. Thats what worried me about hibernate: Most guides are written with the idea that Hibernate is deeply integrated into an application

Comment: Also, if you switch on auto-commit in the middle of a transaction, then the current running transaction will be committed and new one will be started. Ref: JDBC 4.0 Specification.

Comment: @vineet I was thinking just enabling auto commit at start and leaving it alone. BTW, what does happen when I update two persistent objects simultaneously (my app is very multi-threaded)?

Comment: @TheLQ, I have a feeling you need to think about where the  transactions start and end in your application and what role the POJO plays in it. Typically, you would start transactions at the entry points in your business logic before you access any transactional resource, and conduct all transactional activities in that context. I could state more, but that would require looking at your design and code.

Comment: @TheLQ, if you are referring to updates on two entities in the database, then it would depend on the order in which the updates occur to the entities; you might be the typical problems with non-transactional access. If you are sharing Java objects across threads, you're in even more trouble, for you might be changing the state of the entity cache in Hibernate in an undefined manner. I think you need to understand what auto-commit does in greater detail, before embarking on using it.

Comment: @Vineet Transactions are really everywhere. Various points of the program access and (sometimes) add data. I really wrote the program around the idea that access to persistent objects would be easy. The concept of a "unit of work" just isn't there. The only way I might be able to put this concept is Event dispatching, but then I would be opening and closing transactions all the time (not all Listeners of the events modify the objects). And then I have the problem of the abstracted data access layer.

Comment: @TheLQ, I'm not sure what you are doing, so I will comment no more. But, you should read about these three problems: dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads. Then, verify if they will occur in your design if you introduce auto-commits.

Comment: I'll post this in more detail as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of auto-commit, does not mean that transactions are no longer used to access data. It simply means that each statement now executes in it's own transaction. The exact instances when the transaction starts and terminates in defined in the JDBC specification. For the sake of brevity, this usually depends on the nature of the statement executed.

I'm not sure of how your design is implemented, but non-transactional systems typically suffer from three problems. The use of auto-commit may reintroduce one or more of these problems.

**Dirty reads**

Consider a thread A in your application that would read an entity and update it, but not commit the new value. Consider another thread B that reads the same entity and sees the updated value. If thread A were to roll back it's changes, or fail in committing the updated value, then B is essentially using a dirty value, for it performed a dirty read.

On it's own auto-commit does not result in dirty reads. However, if you have a sequence of database read-writes that were originally performed in a single transaction, making the sequence commit after every read/write operation, will result in dirty reads in a different transaction, for your current transaction might simply roll back the change.

**Non-repeatable reads**

In the context of a transaction, reading the same entity (record) twice in the context of a transaction, and seeing a different value on the second read is considered a non-repeatable read. This occurs when a different transaction has committed it's change and an ongoing transaction reads the new value.

Using auto-commit (or rather performing the read operations in two different transactions)  will most likely result in non-repeatable reads, since both the read operations in the same thread will be execute in different transactional contexts, resulting in the second read seeing the committed value (from the transaction in a different thread).

**Phantom reads**

Very similar to non-repeatable reads, but not quite. In this case, the thread of execution performing the second read, will see additional data (and not updated data) in the form of new records.

Likewise, using auto-commit will most likely result in phantom reads in your application for the same reasons.

These issues will also depend on the database transaction isolation levels employed, but eventually when one uses an ORM framework, marking the start and end of transactions would be left to an application developer. While individual read-write operations may be isolated from each other by the database, it is upto the developer to ensure that work occurs in a transactional context. Using auto-commit changes the transaction context for every operation.

**TLDR**

Using auto-commit when performing transactional activities would mean that it is impossible to perform a rollback to a safe state, in the event of a failure during a "business transaction context". As an aside, it is for this reason that auto-commits should be disabled when performing batch updates in JDBC. Using auto-commit will force a commit to occur for every update in the batch, when the real need is to commit at the end of the batch.

I would recommend reading the book [Java Transaction Design Strategies](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/JTDS) (available as a free ebook) to gain further insight into using transactions.

Comment: The first two seem like basic multi-threading Synchronization issues. Note that my application is primarily a large Event-Listener system with all listeners in different threads. Without deeply integrating Hibernate into my application I see two options: 1) Starting a transaction before each Listener executes and closing afterwords (is possible actually) or 2) Use Autocommit and just say that these are basic sync issues that can't easily be solved with my application design. Either of those look like viable options?

Comment: @TheLQ, your option (1) is line with my above comment : "Typically, you would start transactions at the entry points in your business logic before you access any transactional resource, and conduct all transactional activities in that context.". As far as option (2) is concerned, well that depends on what work is done in each Listener. With autocommit, the problem is more with loss of recovery data to roll back. One update would succeed, but another could fail, leaving you to do the janitorial work in the database.

Comment: Wouldn't (1) though hit the same synchronization issues as outlined in your post with Autocommit? The data objects are all shared (its difficult to explain how and why and even more difficult to rewrite the program so not to make it shared) as a mutual resource, so I see all the problems you outlined above.

Comment: If you use option (1), then the outcome depends on the transaction isolation level used by the database. Most databases will automatically operate in a mode that prevents dirty reads. You can operate at a higher isolation level if allowed by the database, to eliminate the other two problems as well. But this is a conscious decision, and it depends on how your application is written - if it reads the same record/table twice, then increasing the isolation level is often done to achieve serializable transactions.

Comment: I think you should read the book that I linked to, at a minimum. There are other books as well, but that's the shortest one that will give you some insight into resolving problems involving transactional access. It took me a couple of hours to finish it, and a few weeks for the other books.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a property 'hibernate.connection.autocommit' that you can set to true either in your hibernate config XML or programatically on your SessionFactory.

It is not clear from your question what benefit that would really offer you over just beginning and committing a transaction inside your Hibernate implementation of the `getObjects(`) interface method.

Comment: Isn't that what autocommit does though essentially?

Comment: That depends on what your interface methods are and how much they do.  If a method takes a bunch of objects and might involve updating several tables, you probably want to be able to roll that back if one fails somewhere.

Comment: So I should be fine with autocommit on most of the fields but write my own Transactions for the relationship fields (Many-To-Many + OneToMany + ManyToOne + OneToOne relationships)?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but from the perspective of the hibernate abstraction, that's kind of a nonsense.  Using hibernate as an implementor for your interfaces just doesn't seem productive.  You're adding all the overhead of a higher level framework to implement lower level interfaces and try to un-do all the work it does abstracting away the details of database interaction.

Comment: The reason I've done that is because the storage location needs to be changable. Depending on the situation my program is used in, a full blown database is not needed for persistent storage. If I didn't have this requirement then I would most likely rewrite some of the project with deep integration into hibernate. But unfortunately I can't